# Inbox assignment in descending order date wise

Tags: workflow, inbox, maximo

Can we change the order of maximo Inbox Assignments in maximo 7.6?
I want to change it to ascending order or descending order alphabetically or date wise, whatever the requirement is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set a default sort order for this portlet. The data is loaded via java and uses the cached sort order property set by the user by clicking on the column headers.

The only way you can allow for sorting options is to add these columns to the portlet.

or you change the code in psdi.webclient.controls.InboxPortlet and set the sortAttribute and sortType to load a property you can manage in Maximo.

You can view the code easily with JD GUI: http://jd.benow.ca/

Some good information on how to get started with changing java code you can find here: http://maximodev.blogspot.nl/p/java-customization.html

Comment: You means mbo customization is the last solution??

Comment: Yes, if you look into that class, you'll find the values there hard coded to null, if they we're an attribute that would be the sort order until the user changes it be clicking on a column header.

Comment: Hmm, okay. For that I must have to learn these things first :(. , Anyway, thanks to u Jeroen,s

Comment: I've updated the answer with some recources, please accept it if you find the answer is correct and give an upvote if you think its helpfull

Comment: Yeah sure and thankyou very much Jeroen. i think I should go to use portlets , also your given link to get into Java customization.